# How to replace ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have presented ViewController1 using this code:

```
let vc1 = ViewController1()
present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, I want to show ViewController2 in ViewController1.

```
@IBAction func buttonEvent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc2 = ViewController2()
    self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is: I want to show the ViewContoller2 while the current ViewController is being dismissed when the button event is called.

And I want to animation while doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want, on buttonEvent ViewController1 should be dismissed and ViewController2 should be displayed with present animation ?

Comment: Yes, I want ViewController2 to opening when ViewController1 is dismissing. If I can make it, I want transition animation here.

Comment: you can use view controller transition animation https://www.raywenderlich.com/173576/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-3

Answer (score 29):

You may achieve this through `navigationController` as follows:

```
guard var viewControllers = sourceViewController.navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }

// Popped ViewController not used
_ = viewControllers.popLast()

// Push targetViewController
viewControllers.append(targetViewController)

sourceViewController.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

Get `viewControllers` in your navigation stack at first. Pop the current and append the target one. Then, set your stack to updated `viewControllers`.

### Additions

(For those who do not use `navigationController`)

I realized a possible problem in the given answer. Thus I want to make this addition. Check [documentation of parent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent) before continue. I want to lay emphasis on this part:

> If the recipient is a child of a container view controller, this
>   property holds the view controller it is contained in. If the
>   recipient has no parent, the value in this property is nil. Prior to
>   iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and was being
>   presented, the presenting view controller would be returned. On iOS 5,
>   this behavior no longer occurs. Instead, use the
>   presentingViewController property to access the presenting view
>   controller.

In brief, if you want to dismiss the current `UIViewController` (`sourceViewController`) and present the next one (`targetViewController`), you should make the `present()` call from `presentingViewController` of the current.

```
weak var presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController

sourceViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    presentingViewController?.present(targetViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
})
```

Though you probably see the transition this time, at the end of the `completion` of `sourceViewController`'s `dismiss()`, the `presentingViewController` will be shown till the `targetViewController` is presented. I don't know whether you expect this behavior. If no, I couldn't come up with a workaround to prevent this for now.

Comment: Nice solution but I don't have navigationController.

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me

```
viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers.remove(at: viewControllers.count - 1)
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "destinationVC", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your app uses **AppDelegate**, **SceneDelegate** and **Storyboard**, assign an identifier to the ViewController you wish to replace the current vc with

```
// replace viewController

let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MyViewControllerIdentifier")

UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController = destinationViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 1] = newViewController
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in `SceneDelegate`, modify the root view controller and access it with  `(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.yourFunctionHere(view: UIViewController)`. unless your app doesnt use a navigation controller or a tab view you can probly just use a presetSegue() function.

https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/